# Linq equivalent of SQL LEFT function?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

We have a database with some fields that are varchar(max) which could contain lots of text however I have a situation where I only want to select the first for example 300 characters from the field for a paginated table of results on a MVC web site for a "preview" of the field.

for a simplified example query where I want to get all locations to display in the table
(this would be paginated, so I don't just get everything - I get maybe 10 results at a time):

```
return db.locations;
```

However this gives me a location object with all the fields containing the massive amounts of text which is very time consuming to execute.

So what I resorted to before was using SQL stored procedures with the:

```
LEFT(field, 300)
```

to resolve this issue and then in the Linq to SQL .dbml file included the stored procedure to return a "location" object for the result.

However I have many queries and I don't want to have to do this for every query.

This maybe a simple solution, but I am not sure how I can phrase this on a search engine, I would appreciate anyone who can help me with this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: I misread `LEFT` for `LTRIM`. Here's all the [String functions that can't be used in LINQ to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882672.aspx). Have you tried `String.Substring()`?

Your best option is to map the stored procedure and continue using it. [Here is an excellent article with screen shots](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/16/linq-to-sql-part-6-retrieving-data-using-stored-procedures.aspx) showing you how to do so.

If you're not using the designer tool [you can also call ExecuteCommand against the DataContext](http://www.willasrari.com/blog/elegant-way-of-executing-a-stored-procedure-using-linq/000312.aspx). It isn't pretty, but it's what we have for now.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply, yes it occurred to me to use substring, but I am using objects i.e. returning "locations" which means i would have to use "select new location { field = field.substring(xyz) etc each time? I don't know even if it would work, but it is also a large object with many fields albeit small in comparison with the large text fields, but it would mean that I would have to select all the fields individually each time I query if you understand me!. In response to your other points, yes I am using stored procedures at the moment with the GUI designer like the tutorial.

Comment: I would guess using select new location { ...} and using substring on the required fields is probably the only way, I guess I thought there might be more elegant way.

Answer (score 5):

You can use functions that directly translate to those functions too, this is useful when you need to translate code that functionally works just fine in SQL at no risk in LINQ.
Have a look at `System.Data.Objects.EntityFunctions`

```
Locations.Select(loc=>System.Data.Objects.EntityFunctions.Left(loc.Field,300))
```

This will get directly translated into a `LEFT` on the server side.

Comment: Oh thanks, I will try this and see if it works if the "substring-ing" does not work

Comment: Unfortunately it only works for Linq to Entities not plain old Linq to SQL apparently as it throw an exception saying this.

Comment: For recent entity framework, you can use `System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.Left(loc.Field,300)`

Answer (score 2):

I found something like this worked for me:

```
return from locationPart in db.locations
       select new LocationPart
       {                       
         Description = locationPart.description,
         Text = locationPart.text.Substring(0,300)                       
       };
```

Not ideal because I have to use "select new" to return a a different object, but it seems to work.