# How to write linq group by left(Column) and left(column)

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql

I have this query in SQL

```
SELECT   DISTINCT '20' + Left(charWeekNo ,2) AS title, COUNT('') AS colspan
FROM Table1 PWeek  
GROUP BY Left(charWeekNo ,2)
```

How to write in linq with above query?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linq equivalent of SQL LEFT function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927672/linq-equivalent-of-sql-left-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var PWeek = Table1
    .GroupBy(x=>x.charWeekNo.Substring(0,2))
    .Select(x=>new{title = "20" + x.Key, colspan = x.Count()})
```

Comment: @Magnus Is it needed? It has a GroupBy

Answer (score 0):

```
var result  =Table1.GroupBy(x=>x.charWeekNo.Substring(0,2))
               .Select(g=>new {title = "20" +g.Key, colspan =g.Count()}).ToList()
```