# How to use SQL Left function in LINQ in C#

Tags: c#

I have a datatable `dt_Customers` which contains ZIP codes and some other data. 
In this data table I want to select only those ZIP codes which are starting with 0 or 1. I am using LINQ, I know in SQL query I can use (left (ZIP,1)) and it will give me the first digit. Is it possible to use LEFT function in LINQ as well?

Here is my code.

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> enumerableDataRowCollection = 
                    from company in dt_Customers.AsEnumerable()
                    where (company.Field<int>("ZIP") == 0 || company.Field<int>("ZIP") ==1) 
                    select company;
```

Comment: check this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927672/linq-equivalent-of-sql-left-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> enumerableDataRowCollection = 
                    from company in dt_Customers.AsEnumerable()
                    let zip = company.Field<string>("ZIP")
                    where (zip.StartsWith("0") || zip.StartsWith("1")) 
                    select company;
```

or

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> enumerableDataRowCollection = 
                    from company in dt_Customers.AsEnumerable()
                    let zip = company.Field<string>("ZIP")
                    where (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(zip) && (zip[0] == '0' || zip[0] == '1') ) 
                    select company;
```